# if array exists in Obj, get array item, if not just get field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

works correctly when nested `obj` arrays ***are*** found; however if *not found* becomes `null` and breaks page. How could I simply check *if exists* before hand, and if not just output next level field?

Below works when both arrays are present in relational data objs - however sometimes `.NextObj` does *not contain* an array but rather just field - in this case it should probably just be called like `.NextObj.field` as opposed to `.NextObj[0].field` which works when array is found. How do you handle both possibilities?

```
html += "<li class='information'>" + item.OutterObj[0].NextObj[0].url + "</li>";
```

---

**Update**; with the below suggestion it is still throwing when the first `item.OutterObj[0]` is found null.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

---

Comment: can you provide the full example code?

Comment: I would question why your data model is in flux so much.

Comment: Check if what you are looking at is an array (instanceof, .isArray(), etc...) and if so, treat as array like you do, if not, treat as an object if you know it will be restricted to one of those two things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried check if it exists first?. Something like this.

```
field = item.OutterObj[0].NextObj[0] ? item.OutterObj[0].NextObj[0].field : item.OutterObj[0].NextObj.field;
html += "<li class='information'>" + field + "</li>";
```

**Update**

For a more generic solution you can use.

```
field = getProperty(item, ['OutterObj','NextObj', 'url']);
html += "<li class='information'>" + field + "</li>";

function getProperty(rootObject, properties){

  properties.forEach(function(property){
    rootObject = rootObject[0] ? rootObject[0][property] : rootObject[property]
  });

  return rootObject;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still failing at .OutterObj[0]